# Strange execution of get accesor in C#?

Tags: c#, getter

I set up a simple program just to test how the code inside a get accessor executes (since I had been having some issues in another project), and found something quite strange:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new TestClass();
        var testBool = test.TestBool;
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    private bool _testBool = true;
    public bool TestBool
    {
        get
        {
            if (_testBool)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("true!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("false! WTF!");
            }
            _testBool = false;
            return _testBool;
        }
    }
}
```

I expected the output to be

```
true!
```

But what I got instead was

```
true!
false! WTF!
```

Just what is going on here?